# Using National Instruments, I want to change the opening of this valve

Tags: c, controls

It is done so by selecting a voltage in GUI, the code carries it out and opens based on how many Volts are ran through it (0 being closed and 5 being wide open). It works fine and dandy, but the issue I run into is when I increase the the voltage by a hundredth, it does not change the flow rate at all unless I go from a significantly larger number or smaller number back to that selected voltage. An example: I chose to go from 2.12 Volts to 2.13 Volts, the flow rate will not change unless I set it from to 2.12 to 0 Volts back up to 2.13 Volts. How can I fix this? My final intent will be to input the specific flow rate I want in LPM and the volts will automatically change.

---

```
GetCtrlVal(panel, Panel_Valve_V, ValveV);
ValveV[1]=1;
DAQmxStartTask (AoutTaskHandle);
DAQmxWriteAnalogF64 (AoutTaskHandle, 1, 1, 0.1, DAQmx_Val_GroupByScanNumber, ValveV, &nSamp, NULL);
DAQmxStopTask (AoutTaskHandle);
```

Comment: This is not a programming question.  You need to discuss with the manufacturer how lash affects minimum step size.

Comment: For different reasons (hysteresis, mechanical friction, ...) it could be indeed necessary to do as you desribe. Please check the manual for a description of needed sequence on top of definition of voltage to flow mapping.

Comment: Please review for intended appearance, based on https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help